# float or flexbox stacking align bottom

Tags: css, css-float, flexbox

Tricky one.

I have a bunch of smaller elements the I want to wrap around a main div. I have these smaller divs floating right and the main div left. I have the smaller elements keeping there height relative to the width using padding-bottom % as below:

```
 <section class="who">
    <aside id="whoText"></aside>
    <article class="profile">profile1</article>
    <article class="profile">profile2</article>
    <article class="profile">profile3</article>
    <article class="profile">profile4</article>
    <article class="profile">profile5</article>
 </section>

.profile{
    background-color:$primaryColour;
    border:1px red dashed;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;;
     &:before {
            content: "";
            float: left;
            //this div will be only half as tall as it is wide
            padding-bottom: 50%;
        }
     &:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }
}
```

This all works nicely, but I'd like the space thats left over at the top not after the last element.
Currenly its like this : (Red box is the space I'm talking about.)

[image: current]

[image: preferred]

but Id like it like this???

Thanks for the input.

Rob.

Comment: please include your HTML markup so people can see how you built this and hopefully help you

Comment: Man anyone gonna help me out? I've tried using JavaScript to set the height of the top right box but this is flacky on resize and sometimes drops the last box down...